# How to show summary of a node in CKEditor?

Tags: nodes, 9

I have a website built with Drupal 9. I publish many articles on it and I would like to display in my articles, the summary rendering entity of other articles related to my writing.

I know this is possible using the Paragraph module, but for simplicity I'd like to do this with CKEditor.

How to display the summary of a node in the body of an essay with CKEditor?

Here is an example (this is not a Drupal site):

https://wonderfall.space/grapheneos-12-1-apps/

We can see that content is integrated into the writing.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed

Comment: @Perhaps Thanks I'll look at that. Doesn't the Media module allow you to do this? It is able to render entity files and images, why doesn't it do nodes?

Comment: Media only does **media** entities.  The generic "embed any entity" solution for Drupal is **Entity Embed**.